# How to modify snippets in Sublime 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to change up my for loop snippets in Sublimetext 3.

One example is the forv for vector loop. I'd like to have that use an auto iterator instead of a vector iterator, as I often use std::array.

But I can't find these snippets anywhere, or where to edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is overriding snippets. Create a snippet with the same name as you want to override and save it to User packages directory. Details are given [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html). Most easy way to find User packages directory is Browse Packages Menu Option. It will show you the directory where user packages saved.

I looked at where sublime installed and found C++.package file (MacOS /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages\C++.sublime-package) . I unarchived it and found snippets.

Your snippet is following

```
<snippet>
    <description>Vector For Loop</description>
    <content><![CDATA[for (std::vector<$1>::iterator ${3:i} = $2.begin(); $3 != $2.end(); ++$3)
{
    $0
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>forv</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.c, source.objc, source.c++, source.objc++</scope>
</snippet>
```

Create New snippet and copy paste this code. Change it according to your tastes. Save it to default snippet directory.

Comment: You can use https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer to view packaged files. Saving them will place the override in the proper location. It's a plugin I wrote, but I feel it saves some trouble of finding/extracting packages.